# mysql trigger : check how much time left until timestamp column value expires

Tags: mysql, triggers

in my table i have a column named `timstamp_col`  , i have trigger BEFORE UPDATE on the table  .

basically what i want is (in the trigger) to extend `timstamp_col` by 1 hour if there is more than 1 hour left till the timstamp_col value expires , or by 30 minute if there is less then 1 hour left til timstamp_col expires

im not sure how can i check how much time left (in minutes preferably) till the timestampl value expires ... i want something like this

*pleas ignore syntax errors*

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER  update_timestamp BEFORE UPDATE  
    ON  table  
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  

IF OLD.timstamp_col - NOW() > 60 THEN 
 SET NEW.timestamp_col = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
END IF ;

IF OLD.timstamp_col - NOW() < 60 THEN 
 SET NEW.timestamp_col = NOW() + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
END IF ; 



     END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please provide the (minimum) table definition for this or a http://sqlfiddle.com/ for this. The trigger looks correct, so why not fixing the syntax errors and try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for UNIX_TIMESTAMP  , it calculates time in seconds

```
IF UNIX_TIMESTAMP(OLD.timstamp_col) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() < 3600 THEN 
 SET NEW.timestamp_col = NOW() + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
END IF ;
```